# Digitally Signed certificates in webapi C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have two Web API solutions i.e., Client and Server wherein SSL certificate is used to validate authenticity for SSL.

As a Web API Client, what are the things I need to be aware of(parameters to be passed while making a call to server) when the server sends me the certificate generally?

a) How to generate .pfx file and where to store it?

b) Do I need to pass client's IP address so that server can whitelist it?

c) Do I need to generate a private key to pass it to the certificate?

d) Should I be aware of any algorithms that the server is typically going to use to generate certificate?

e) Should it be created in both the web api servers since it is not hosting?

Is there any code example with guidance on each step of this?